# Rails: display events with calendar_date_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, events, calendar

I'm trying to display events in calendar generated by [calendar_date_select](http://code.google.com/p/calendardateselect/) plugin for Rails.

I have `Concert` model with datetime field `date`.

Can I somehow throw in `@concerts` which equals `Concert.all` to `calendar_date_select_tag` to display links to make days where concert is clickable?

I would like to stick to this helper cause I would like to use it as a pure date picker in other places of my app, but have no idea how to achieve my goal.

Sorry if this question is lame, I'm very new to magic Rails world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the plugin currently allows for this.
You can certainly put in a feature request though - look at the bottom of the page and send an email to the main guy!